# Handling (consuming) key press

Tags: java, swing, events, keyboard

I started playing with java a little bit, after few years of coding in C#. What I am trying to achieve is to handle a key press event for jTextField.

In C# i would code:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

I did a little research and read that I can use consume() in java. So i wrote the following code:

```
    if (evt.getKeyChar() == '.' || DataController.getInstance().isDot_pressed()) 
    {
        jTextFieldQuery.setText(DataController.getInstance().generateText(jTextFieldQuery.getText()));

        if(evt.getKeyChar()!='.')
        {
            DataController.getInstance().setOdgovor(DataController.getInstance().getOdgovor()+evt.getKeyChar());
        }
        else
        {
            DataController.getInstance().setDot_pressed(!DataController.getInstance().isDot_pressed());
        }

        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

This code should handle key pres for "." and every key press until another "." is pressed in the mean time it loads predefined text in text field.
This solution doesn't work, it consumes(handles) for example delete button but it doesn't handle normal letters.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I started to post an answer but I just don't have time this morning to write one properly. It's probably the case that you should use e.g. a `DocumentListener` instead when trying to respond to changes in a text field (`ChangeListener` might also work, but it's been awhile and I don't remember the exact details of how `ChangeListener` works with `JTextField`). It would also be good if you updated your question with a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you're trying to do more specifically so we can suggest a correct alternate.

Comment: @Radiodef What if I just wanted to enable digits not letters, how would you do that?

Comment: You would use a `DocumentFilter`. There's a bit of a tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). There are other examples on this site as well, but I don't have time to find a good one.

Comment: `This code should handle key pres for "." and every key press until another "." is pressed in the mean time it loads predefined text in text field.` - I don't understand your requirement. Give a practical example of how you expect the user to use the text field.

Comment: `KeyListener` is never a good choice for text components. Have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for a better solution. The problem with your approach is multi levelled. Because the `KeyEvent` is been triggered outside of the document model, you have no way to know if the model has been updated already or not